# Multiprocessing - cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I try to parrallelize a function which predict different ARIMA model in order to have a kind of gridsearch but I get an error when I run my code. The error is : cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object.

```
def forecast_accuracy(Model, forecast, actual):
    mape = np.mean(np.abs(forecast - actual)/np.abs(actual))  # MAPE
    me = np.mean(forecast - actual)             # ME
    mae = np.mean(np.abs(forecast - actual))    # MAE
    mpe = np.mean((forecast - actual)/actual)   # MPE
    rmse = np.mean((forecast - actual)**2)**.5  # RMSE
    corr = np.corrcoef(forecast, actual)[0,1]   # corr
    mins = np.amin(np.hstack([forecast[:,None], 
                              actual[:,None]]), axis=1)
    maxs = np.amax(np.hstack([forecast[:,None], 
                              actual[:,None]]), axis=1)
    minmax = 1 - np.mean(mins/maxs)             # minmax
    
    return({'Model':Model,'mape':mape, 'me':me, 'mae': mae, 'mpe': mpe, 
            'rmse':rmse, 'corr':corr, 'mins':mins, 'maxs':maxs, 'minmax':minmax})


def metrics_ARIMA(models_ARIMA, train_arima, test_arima):
    dfmetrics_ARIMA = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Model", "mape", "me", "mae", "mpe", "rmse", "corr", "minmax"])
    for i in range(0,6):
        for j in range(0,6):
            dfmetrics_ARIMA = dfmetrics_ARIMA.append(forecast_accuracy(f"ARIMA{i}{d_optimum}{j}", models_ARIMA[f"ARIMA{i}{d_optimum}{j}"].predict(len(train_arima), len(train_arima)+len(test_arima)-1, typ='levels'), test_arima), ignore_index=True)
    return dfmetrics_ARIMA
```

After that, I run :

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    metrics_ARIMA = executor.submit(metrics_ARIMA, models_ARIMA, train_arima, test_arima)
    metrics_ARIMA = metrics_ARIMA.result()
```

Comment: Admittedly that error message is rather unhelpful, I believe what is happening there is it is failing to serialise one of your objects. Since you are trying to multithread your program, python has to put all of you data into a file to send it over to the worker thread. Unfortunately, one of you objects is unable to be serialised like this, and so it throws an error. I have no way to know which object could be causing this problem, but you could test it yourself by using `pickle.dump()` on all of the objects you are trying to pass into `executor.submit()`. Hopefully that will help.